# Get Index Given Row and Column

Tags: c++

Is there a formula that can be used to get the index given the current column and row? The following is what I have so far. The problem is, however, that the code only works for the first row...

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        index = i * (columns - 1) + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: index = i * columns + j

Comment: You do not need a loop there, you can calculate the index directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
        index = i * columns + j;
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thanks